How can I configure a custom domain with SSL/TLS (HTTPS) for my GitHub Pages
How can I configure a custom domain with SSL/TLS (HTTPS) for my GitHub Pages site hosted on a project page (aliqasum54321.github.io)?"
Here are the things that have been tried off:
1)Utilizing a third-party service or tool that offers SSL/TLS support for custom domains on GitHub Pages, such as Cloudflare.
2)Setting up a reverse proxy with a service like Netlify, which allows for custom domain configuration and SSL/TLS certificates.

Here is part of the description of the git tag you included: Do not use this tag for GitHub/GitHub Actions questions that do not involve git usage; use [github] or [github-actions] instead. Do not use the [github] tag for Git-related issues just because a repository happens to be hosted on GitHub.
